# unable to use Paketo-buildpacks/Bellsoft-liberica - JDK version11.0.19 - using Binding/Dependency Mapping - Cloud Native Buildpack

Tags: java, buildpack, paketo

**i want to use version 11.0.19 present locally instead of downloading from online. So am trying the [binding/Dependency Mapping](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#dependency-mappings) to implement this
**

### getting below ERROR after executing command

```
   ===> DETECTING
======== Output: paketo-buildpacks/git@1.0.6 ========
failed to load bindings from '/platform/bindings': failed to read 
binding 'dependency-mapping': missing 'type'
err:  paketo-buildpacks/git@1.0.6 (1)
======== Output: paketo-buildpacks/git@1.0.6 ========
failed to load bindings from '/platform/bindings': failed to read 
binding 'dependency-mapping': missing 'type'
err:  paketo-buildpacks/git@1.0.6 (1)
```

### Expecting

while creating image from source code using buildpacks, by default it is downloading from internet, But i want to use version 11.0.19 in my local path instead. I have used **paketobuildpacks/builder:base** as a builder. And bt(binding-tool) for downloading all the dependencies.

```
**Bell Soft Liberica JDK 11.0.19: Contributing to layer**
    Downloading from from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.19+7/bellsoft-jdk11.0.19+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Verifying checksum 
Expanding to / layers/paketo-bu ildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jdk 
Adding 137 container CA certificates to JVM truststore 
Writing env. build/ JAVA HOME.override 
Writing env. build/ JDK HOME.override 
**
**
```

**executed below command**

```
pack build binding_test:sep4 --path . --volume /home/ubuntu/binding_tool-v1.20.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bindings/dependency-mapping:/platform/bindings/dependency-mapping/binaries --env BP_JVM_VERSION=11.0.19 --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

steps followed. as mentioned in [LINK](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#dependency-mappings)

```
echo "file:///bindings/dependency-mapping/binaries/bellsoft-jdk11.0.19+7-linux-amd64.tar.gz" >> 138f8bd3801445391ff19d683ea7f3c4662dcd0e2cd0b8ab2a5d3966b05124f8
```

created file **type** as below

```
echo "dependency-mapping" >> type
```

Please help me where am doing it wrong.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, but the text directly.

Comment: First thing, the easiest way to set up bindings is with binding-tool. You tell it which buildpack, and it'll download the dependencies and make the bindings for you. Then all you need to do is mount the volume, which it can even help you do also. https://github.com/dmikusa/binding-tool. Even if you don't want to use this tool, it's a good example of what you need to do for bindings to work, you could start with what it generates and modify them as well.

Comment: Second thing, if you want to troubleshoot your set up you need to post more info. Need to know what you're putting into the binding files, i.e `type` and `138f...`. Then we need to see the output of running the build with the dep mapping binding present. Lastly, I would suggest running the build a second time with these additional arguments `pack build -v -e BP_DEBUG=true ...` because it'll give some more helpful debug information.

Comment: added binding files content in the question and have also ran the build now adding DEBUG variable. No helpful info in the debug logs.

Comment: @DanielMikusa - have updated the new error am getting  while using the binding. Please help me where am going wrong

Comment: Try `--volume /home/ubuntu/binding_tool-v1.20.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bindings:/bindings` and set `-e SERVICE_BINDING_ROOT=/bindings` with `pack build` also.